# Control Version System for webSites

Tags: version-control, cvs

I work as a webmaster with another guy, who is gonna moving away from our city. We're thinking of using a control version system to keep on working but we 're looking for help choosing one.

We do not develop big heavily-coded sites, but small presentation sites (you can have an example [here](http://www.argentovivoband.com) )

The most important things are: 
we have to work on the same files from different city (even states :D)
we wont to keep trace of different version of each file (so we can easily roll back to a previous version).

It would be nice if we can trace picture change too.

Last but not least: we're using a VPS (debian/lenny+apache2) for testing sites. It would be very nice (but not necessary) to have the new site version (after a new commit) directly visible in a web brower

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Note that CVS isn't used much for new projects.  Subversion is similar (in principle) but improved.  It also provides a web browser view.

Comment: yes, I've started working with SVN on a private server and eclipse pdt svn integration. When I wrote "control version sistem" i meant generci software for versioning =)